# why mongodb database connections cannot release?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Recently，I get some problem with spring-data-mongodb,can you help me ?
the version info:

mongodb version： 3.2
spring-data-mongodb version ： 1.9.1

Now I use spring-data-mongodb to deal with my DAO layer. But I find that the database connections is increasing，it seems the database connections cannot release .

Thanks !

Comment: How are you confirming that connections are increasing?

Comment: I use the command on the application server like this ：` netstat -anultp | grep 27017 | wc`  , the number is increasing always,no reduce.